# Hadoop MapReduce: with fixed number of input files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

for Map Reducer Job

In my input directory having around 1000 files. and each files contains some GB's of data.

for example `/MyFolder/MyResults/in_data/20140710/` contains 1000 files.

when I give the inputpath as `/MyFolder/MyResults/in_data/20140710` it's taking all 1000 files to process.

I would like to run a job by talking 200 files only at a time. How we can do this?

Here my command to execute:

```
hadoop jar wholefile.jar com.form1.WholeFileInputDriver -libjars myref.jar -D mapred.reduce.tasks=15 /MyFolder/MyResults/in_data/20140710/ <<Output>>
```

Can any help me, how to run a job like a batch size for the inputfiles.

Thanks in advance

-Vim

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to modify your driver to take only 200 files as input out of all the files in that directory. Something like this:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
FileStatus[] files = fs.globStatus(new Path("/MyFolder/MyResults/in_data/20140710/*"));
for (int i=0;i<200;i++) {
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, files[i].getPath());
}
```